# how to animate css element only when it appears on a window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

i know that there is parallax but i want something else like in this website [joinhandshake.com](https://joinhandshake.com/)

for example i have this code 
**html**

```
<div class="black-div"></div>
   <div class="animated-div">
       <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit temporibus fuga sit quam fugit! Dignissimos quis qui, praesentium id nihil, aspernatur nostrum, dolores dolor molestiae error molestias ipsum ipsam at.</h1>
   </div>
```

**css**

```
.black-div {
    background-color: black;
    height: 130vh;
}
 @keyframes rotate-scale-up {
    0% {
      transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0);
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(2) rotateZ(180deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1) rotateZ(360deg);
    }
  }
  .animated-div {
    animation: rotate-scale-up 0.65s linear both;
}
```

the problem is that when i load the page, the text gets animated, so how can i prevent that?

Comment: You cannot do that just via CSS. You need JS to check if the element is in the viewport and then apply a given class name, ie. visible, inViewport or revealed then apply styles

Comment: @Arber Sylejmani so you mean i need to add an event listener??, if so, what that event would be ??

Comment: You can use getBoundingClientRect() to test when your element enters the viewport and then dynamically add a class to it to do the animation.  https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: @ecg8 i just read that article and came back for some insight lol, thank you!

Comment: Just a couple things I've used in the past for this when I just want to get it done. [WOWjs](https://wowjs.uk/) is handy for the simpler stuff and [ScrollMagic](https://scrollmagic.io/) when you want to get even cooler. Enjoy tinkering!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if an element is in view, use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). This API is built for this exact purpose and requires little to no calculations, only a check with the `isIntersecting` value, to see if an element has entered the view.

The IntersectionObserverIn uses a *callback function* to do something whenever an element has entered or left the view. In this function you can specify what should happen when that does.

I've made a snippet with an example on how it works and how you can implement it.

```js
/**
 * What to do when an item enters the screen
 * If it is in the screen, isIntersecting will be true.
 * Add a class when it is.
 */
const intersectionCallback = (entries) => {
  for (const entry of entries) { // Loop over all elements that either enter or exit the view.
    if (entry.isIntersecting) { // This is true when the element is in view.
      entry.target.classList.add('show'); // Add a class.
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Create a observer and use the instersectionCallback as 
 * the instructions for what to do when an element enters
 * or leaves the view
 */
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCallback);

/**
 * Get all .item elements and loop over them.
 * Observe each individual item.
 */
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
for (const item of items) {
  observer.observe(item);
}
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

.item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #333;
}

.item:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.item.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Hello</div>
<div class="item">Hello</div>
<div class="item">Hello</div>
<div class="item">Hello</div>
<div class="item">Hello</div>
<div class="item">Hello</div>
<div class="item">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Then page fully loaded delay element use jQuery instead.

```
  setTimeout(function () {
  $("div").addClass("black-div").delay(2000).fadeIn(); 
  });
```